# Is it possible to order a Django Model using the active language?

Tags: python, django, django-models, internationalization

I'm working on Django 1.5.1 and I'm wondering the following question: Is it possible to define ordering in a model on a translatable field, using `django-transmeta` and using the active language the user is accessing the admin?

So far, I achieved to use the translated field and to order using the default language, not the active one, as the call to `get_language()` always returns the default defined in `settings.py` if I call the method from Meta class (or from a ModelAdmin class).

Here is the code I'm working on, and thanks for your help:

```
class StartupType(models.Model):

    __metaclass__ = TransMeta

    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=30, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=30, unique=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = _("Startup type")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Startup types")
        translate = (
            "name",
        )
        ordering = [
            "name_" + LANGUAGE_CODE,
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering) you can define a `get_ordering()` method to use a dynamic order:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import StartupType

class StartupTypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_ordering(self, request):
        language_code = request.LANGUAGE_CODE[:2]
        return ('name_%s' % language_code,)

admin.site.register(StartupType, StartupTypeAdmin)
```

This works as well using `get_language()` instead of `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`.

If you still do not get the correct language, make sure you added the Locale middleware **after** the Session middleware in your `settings.py`, e.g.:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware', 
)
```

**EDIT:** Added alternative to define dynamic ordering on the Model.

If you also want to set `ordering` on the model class, is seems a tad bit more complicated, this is the best I could come up with:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.options import Options
from django.utils.translation import get_language
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from transmeta import TransMeta, get_real_fieldname


class TranslatedOptions(Options):
    @property
    def ordering(self):
        lang = get_language()[:2]
        return [get_real_fieldname(f, lang) for f in self.orig_ordering]

    @ordering.setter
    def ordering(self, value):
        self.orig_ordering = value


class TransMetaOrdering(TransMeta):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new_class = super(TransMetaOrdering, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        options = TranslatedOptions(None)
        for k, v in new_class._meta.__dict__.iteritems():
            setattr(options, k, v)
        new_class._meta = options
        return new_class


class StartupType(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = TransMetaOrdering

    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(_("Slug"), max_length=30, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Startup type")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Startup types")
        translate = (
            "name",
        )
        ordering = (
            "name",
        )
```

This will replace `StartupType._meta` (an object of type `django.db.models.options.Options`) with a new object of type `TranslatedOptions` which will expose `ordering` as a dynamic property.

Comment: Hi NCao! I tried using `get_ordering()` and it worked well! :) I also fixed the order in `Locale` middleware after `Session`. Is there a way to specify "dynamic ordering based on active language" in the Model instead of ModelAdmin? I also tried to use `get_language()` for the `search_fields`, but it always returns the default language, not the active one :( Do you have any ideas on these topics? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Caumons It is actually possible to define dynamic ordering on the model, although quite complicated, so it might be easier to just delegate the dynamic part to the view.

As for `search_fields`, I believe a simple property on the `ModelAdmin` would work. It will be evaluated inside `ModelAdmin.changelist_view`, hence using the current language as required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You're right, setting the ordering directly in the Model is too complex, so it's far better to move it to the corresponding views. I tried your suggestion for the `search_fields` using a property, but I'm afraid this field doesn't allow using callables. So I think this won't be possible, and only one language (default) will be searchable.